# Anyone know some sites that have a korean short stories?

Tags: spoken-korean, resources

I'm hunting for some sites that has korean short stories. I'm trying to find them coz' I want vocabularies and construction I am an intermediate learner but can't find find some sites with such short stories.

Comment: Are you looking for audio stories (as you added the spoken-Korean tag)? Or just anything?

Comment: i prefer with audio but if not it's ok without it :) (for vocab also)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://18children.president.pa.go.kr/mobile/our_space/fairy_tales.php

This is the website serviced by the government of South Korea. 100 kinds of Korean fairy tales are provided. Since this website is targeting children, vocabularies and grammar are easy to understand. (Elementary school student level)

Comment: @NAVY welcome to the site! If you found the answer helpful please don't forget to upvote (the triangle above the number to the right of the answer) or accept (the tick mark) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://section.blog.naver.com/BlogHome.nhn

Korean blog, stories but its all in korean languages.